# Pandas: columns versus (multi)indices for scientific programming?

Tags: python, pandas, scientific-computing

In my research, I have many cases where I have a Pandas table with many different combinations of variables and descriptors (for example, different subjects, brain regions, analysis parameters, etc.). The size of my data are on the order of hundreds of thousands of rows (sometimes). Often I'll want to do things like average across certain variables collapsing across values of the others, or plot one variable with respect to the other, and so on. My question is: are there general rules of thumb for when it is best to treat a variable as a data column vs. as an index? My understanding is that treating things as an index makes subsetting easier, and lookups faster, but has the disadvantage of being immutable. Thus far I have been adopting the strategy of just treating everything as a column, but I am wondering what advantages I would gain using the indexing features, and when it would be best to use them.

I've attached an example of my data; each row is a single trial, the last column ('acc') is the data for that trial (doesn't matter, but it's whether a classifier was correct or incorrect about its prediction for that trial), and all the other columns are other information about that trial (e.g., the subject, which brain area, which analysis options were used for that trial, etc.). So I am wondering whether it is generally better (in terms of easy data management, aggregating, plotting, etc.) to treat the non-data columns as indices or as columns with Pandas. [image: Example Data]

Comment: Perhaps you can add a representative sample of data for demonstration purposes?

Comment: sounds more like an SQL question. There you would set indexes on some variables to access them faster but in pandas the index  should be unique ( unique combinations) , s.t. you can identify the rows.

Comment: Alright, attached data.

With regard to Marvin's question: so is the rule of thumb that any non-data information that suffices to uniquely identify a row should be treated as an index?

Comment: Any other thoughts on this?